# Why is this working? I cannot understand the logic of this swapping

Tags: c++, string, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```cpp
int main() {
    // Complete the program
    string a,b;
    getline(cin,a);
    getline(cin,b);
    cout<<a.size()<<" ";
    cout<<b.size();
    string c=a+b;
    cout<<endl<<c;

    swap(a[0],b[0]);
    cout<<endl<<a<<" "<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
void swap(string s1,string s2){
    string temp=s1;
    s1=s2;
    s2=temp;
}
```

Well the target is to swap the first element of both strings, but I created a general function for that and even got it right. But, unexpectedly, I didn't use pass by reference or pointer! Even then, the changes are permanent when I try to output a and b in the end!

Logically it shouldn't work but it ***is*** working. Is it something to do with the strings?

Comment: Note: [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) exists.

Comment: Post all of your code, including the header inclusions, not snippets.  There is a `std::swap` function, and more than likely, that function is the one being called.

Comment: Could you tell us which input for a and b you used? I agree, this shouldn't be working...

Comment: Did you know that I'm telepathic? I happen to know that you have `using namespace std;` at the beginning of your code, even though you failed to show it. I should go into fortune-telling...

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Yes, it's to do with std::swap name ambiguity. One of you should make an answer.

Comment: `a[0]` and `b[0]` are individual `char` references. It's not calling your function which takes strings.

Comment: `std::string` does not have a constructor that takes a single `char` by itself, so `swap(a[0],b[0])` will NEVER be able to call `void swap(string s1,string s2)`, no matter what you do with namespaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to the fact that, somewhere in code that you have not shown us, you have this line (or something very similar):

```cpp
using namespace std;
```

With this line included, then that very `namespace std` defines a function as follows:

```cpp
void swap(_Ty& _Left, _Ty& _Right);
```

Where the `_Ty` template is replaced with `char` in your `swap(a[0],b[0]);` call.

Add a simple `cout << "My Swap" << endl;` line to **your** `swap` function, and you'll see it's not being called.

Highly recommended reading: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073).

Comment: thanks a lot i got it! but even though i am defining swap in my own way; the function of the namespace is being used!

Comment: Yes - the compiler will find the 'best match' to your call, which is *not* the one you provided. Replace `using namespace std;` with lines like `using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl; using std::string;` and the compiler will then give you an error that the fuction call is wrong.

Comment: if i remove the namespace std; it should actually work because then the best match will be the function defined by me; isnt it?

Comment: @GaganrajdeepSingh No, because your function takes strings while you give it single characters.

Comment: @BessieTheCow isnt that allowed? i may have seen problems where single char values works fine with strings!

Comment: @GaganrajdeepSingh There is no conversion from a single character to an `std::string`, although some overloaded operators for `std::string` accept single characters.